# nodejs broadcast in a room console logs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I broadcast an event in the room along with some data, it is showing that event n times in console. where n = number of players in the room.

If 10 players are in the room then for any broadcast in that room, I will get 10 messages of that event with data on console.

My question is = Whatever I mentioned above is correct or not ? I am getting multiple logs on console that are equal to count of players in the room, hence need to confirm this.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Code, please. We're not mindreaders.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - Question = Whatever I mentioned above is correct or not ? I am getting too many logs on console hence need to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming that your question is "how do I prevent all those messages from being logged")

The default log level for `socket.io` is 3 (*debug*).

You can use `io.set()` to change it to a less verbose level:

```
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(...);

  io.set('log level', 1);
```

According to [the configuration page of socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO), these are the possible log levels:

- 0 – error
- 1 – warn
- 2 – info
- 3 – debug (the default)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, but I would like to have console logs ON.

Comment: So why are you writing you're getting "**too many** logs on console"? I would assume that means that you want to turn them off.

Comment: That is what I want to know, if room has 10 players then after broadcasting I get 10 logs i.e eventName+data displayed for 10 times.
Is it related to number of players in the room ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I understand that was a silly question.

Comment: Well, it wasn't silly at all, it just wasn't clear what you were asking :)